# How to let datetime.strptime parse zero-padded decimal number only

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

The doc says the format is **zero-padded**. But this only works for `datetime.strftime`, not for `datetime.strptime`.

How to make `datetime.strptime` strictly parse *zero-padded number* only? And throw an exception in other case.

> %H Hour (24-hour clock) as a **zero-padded decimal number**.   00, 01, ..., 23
>   %m Month as a **zero-padded** decimal number.  01, 02, ..., 12

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2015111', '%Y%m%d%H')
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

The expected behavior would throw an exception, as `zero-padded decimal number` not found. This can be done by checking the length of the time_ts depend on the format. But I have to change the expected length according to different format, which was not so good.

Comment: That is interesting. I think you're going to have to test the length - to make it general you could have a dictionary mapping format code to expected length and sum over the format codes in the string, but that seems a little complicated.

Comment: Yes, that's just the hard part. Looking for a common solution.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I don't think there is one, you will have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Feels like I have to re-implement the format parsing of `datetime` module, which is not a good idea. Looking for a better solution as parsing the ts in a strict way.

Comment: Yes, I understand all of that, but I'm telling you that (AFAIK, in the standard library) there isn't one. Maybe look into the other Python date parsing libraries?

Comment: Well, pity. Thank you all the same.