# datetime - how to require 2-digit days and months?

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, datetime

I've been using the datetime module to do some checking of dates to see if they are in mm/dd/yyyy or mm/dd/yy formats.  The problem is that the %d and %m directives aren't sensitive enough to detect when the month or day is a single digit, which is a requirement of mine.

```
datetime.strptime('01/01/2001', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

works like I want it to, but

```
datetime.strptime('1/1/2001', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

also produces a valid datetime, when I really want it to throw a ValueError unless the month and day are 0-padded.  Does anyone know how to set a required precision for datetime formats?  Is this possible or should I just go with regex instead?

Comment: Check this out: http://strftime.org/. It may matter which platform you are on. `'%-m/%-d/%Y'`

Comment: I think this cannot be strictly checked with `datetime` unfortunately. Related question: [How to let datetime.strptime parse zero-padded decimal number only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035441/how-to-let-datetime-strptime-parse-zero-padded-decimal-number-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `datetime` function you're using isn't intended to validate input, only to convert strings to `datetime` objects. Both of your examples are legitimate string inputs as far as `datetime` is concerned.

If you want to enforce user input to be a specific format, I would go with a regex - see this example from my REPL:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$")
>>> def valid_datestring(datestring):
...     if pattern.match(datestring):
...         return True
...     return False
...
>>> valid_datestring('1/1/2001')
False
>>> valid_datestring('01/01/2001')
True
```

If you want to define a function that returns a formatted date or returns a valueError, you can do something like this:

```
def format_datestring(datestring):
    if not valid_datestring(datestring):
        raise ValueError('Date input must be in the form dd/mm/yyyy!')
    return datetime.strptime(datestring, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Yeah I figured this was the case, I just thought I had read somewhere about setting precision in datetime format.  Thanks, this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that a string conforms exactly to a formatting string by **re-formatting the `datetime` and comparing to the original string:**

```
datetime_ = datetime.strptime(datetime_string, DATETIME_FORMAT)
if datetime_.strftime(DATETIME_FORMAT) != datetime_string:
    [fail]
```